# What is an example of a birational morphism with a positive-dimensional fiber?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

By a *birational morphism* I mean a morphism $f : X \to Y$ which is birational with its image.

**Question:** What is an example of a birational morphism with a positive-dimensional fiber?

Obviously this can't happen at points in the domain of the rational map $g : f(X) \dashrightarrow X$ which inverts $f$.  But I can't figure out how to produce a nice example.  Any ideas?

(Motivation: I'm looking at Kempf's result that the pushforward of the normal bundle to a fiber is the tangent cone, as presented in ACGH Lemma II.1.1, and trying to picture a situation where the normal bundle isn't simply the tangent bundle.  So ideally I'd like an example where $X$ and $Y$ are complex manifolds and $f$ is a proper holomorphic map under which $X$ is bimeromorphic to its image.  But any example helps!)

Comment: What about a blow-up morphism? It is projective (hence proper) and birational.

Comment: Okay, that helps.  I'd thought of resolving a curve singularity by blowing up but it didn't help, but I think the example I should use is to take $Y$ to be three-space, $f(X)$ a cylinder, and $X$ the blowing up of the cone point.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, if I may add my 2 cents: the first example you should understand is blowing up $\mathbf{A}^2$ in a point!

Comment: Well, computing the tangent cone to $\mathbb{A}^2$ at a point by hand is far easier than applying the theorem.

Comment: (But yes, my question does sound silly in retrospect.  I'd initially put *all* the conditions of the theorem into the question, then tried to strip it down to essentials, and didn't carefully think about what I was asking when I got it reduced to this point.)